# Get details of a currently logged in user

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have am trying to get the admin rights of a user which is either true or false. I do not think i am getting the current logged in users details, the below code is what i have but when i debug it, it seems that it loops through all the users in the firebase table and if any are true it sets the buttons to visible

```
 databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    //  buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //   buttonAddBeverages.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference currentUserReference = databaseUsers.child(uid);
    currentUserReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot userSnapshot) {
            if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
                User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                if(user.getAdminUser() == true)
                {
                    buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonAddBeverages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.i("myInfoTag", "Connection problem");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore exceptions
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're listening for all users, then loop over them, and if any of them is an admin, you show the buttons.

If you only want to show the buttons for the current user, you should only query the current users. Within your current data model that can be something like:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference currentUserReference = databaseUsers.child(uid);
currentUserReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            User user = venueSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            if(user.getAdminUser() == true)
            {
                buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonAddBeverages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore exceptions
    }
});
```

Not only will that give you the behavior you want, it also drastically reduces the bandwidth your app uses.

Comment: HI thanks for this, i am still having some issues if you dont mind helping me.

Comment: the code is now getting the correct Uid for the user and gets as far as the if statement but it does not seem to reach any further when i debug it.

Comment: if (dataSnapshot.exists()) { //this is the point the code reaches

Comment: If it doesn't go into that `if`, it means that there is no node for the user. It's hard to say more without seeing the JSON of your database. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I updated the code with what i have, i added a connection log, it skips the if statement straight to that because the user is showing as null. I have attached an image of the exported JSOn file. I just cant seem to pass in the details for that user for some reason

Comment: I have it working now, thanks for your help I really apreciate it, I updated my code with a working version

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when we are referring to Firebase, we cannot speak about tables. In a NoSQL database there are no tables. There are only pairs of key and value.

To solve your problem, i recomand you change your database a little bit, by adding a new node in your Firebase database named `userAdmins`. When you add a user into your database and is also an admin, add him in this new section. Your new node should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- userAdmins
            |
            --- userId1: true
            |
            --- userId2: true
```

This practice is named **`denormalization`** and for that i recomand you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). If you'll see this video, you'll have a better understanding about this practice.

To verify if a user is admin, just use `exists()` method on the `DataSnapshot` object like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("userAdmins").child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which `uid` is the id of the user you want to verify if is an admin.